# How to calculate webpage load time in android device?

Tags: android, python, url, performance-testing

I am looking for some automation scripts / tool running on my android device to calculate exact webpage load time . I tried scripting using qpython but it was not successful . I have some 5 test URL to be verified their complete load time on default browser and google crome browser . I need to do 10 iterations to calculate average load time for each URL . Please Help. 
Device - Android
URLS - Msn.com, cnn.com..
Browser - Default device browser, crome
Iteration -10

Comment: _I have written a python script to calculate the time take for each webpage to load , But it is not working on QPython Please help . Or any other tool where i can run this program on android device._ 'from urllib.request import urlopen
import time

url = ["http://www.msn.com","http://www.cnn.com","http://www.google.com"]
for i in range(0,5):
    for x in url:
        nf = urlopen(x)
        start = time.time()
        page = nf.read()
        end = time.time()
        lt = (end - start)
        print (x,round(lt,2))
        nf.close()'

Comment: `from urllib.request import urlopen
import time

url = ["http://www.msn.com","http://www.cnn.com","http://www.google.com"]
for i in range(0,5):
    for x in url:
        nf = urlopen(x)
        start = time.time()
        page = nf.read()
        end = time.time()
        lt = (end - start)
        print (x,round(lt,2))
        nf.close()`

Answer (score 1):

For page and javascript profiling in Chrome you can use the [Chrome remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) tool.